# javascript.i want to fix input of textbox through javascript function

Tags: javascript

Hello guys I want to fix my textbox input

Here is my HTML code

```
<marquee behavior="slid" direction="right">Wellcome To Our Medicine Store</marquee>
<div id="inps">
    Search Medicine:  <input type="text" name="n1" id="n1">
    <button onclick="search()" >Search</button>
    <br><br>
    Quantity Of Medicine:<input type="text" name="n3" id="n3">
    <br><br>
    Remaining Stock:<input type="text" name="n2" id="n2">
    <br><br>
    Total Bill:<input type="text" name="n4" id="n4">
</div>
```

Here is my function

```
<script>
var database=[];
// var total_quantity=100;
// var counter=0;
var panadol={
    medicine_name:"panadol",
    price:12,
    total_stock:2000
};
var favrine={
    medicine_name:"favrine",
    price:38,
    total_stock:1200
};
var rivotril={
    medicine_name:"rivotril",
    price:24,
    total_stock:1500
};
database.push(panadol);
database.push(favrine);
database.push(rivotril);
console.log(database);

function search()
{
    var searchmedi=document.getElementById("n1").value;
    var getQuantity=document.getElementById("n3").value;
    var medilist=" ";
    var result="";
    var remaing_stock;

    for(var i=0;i<database.length;i++)
    {

        if(database[i].medicine_name==searchmedi)
        {
                // medilist +='<li>' + database[i].medicine_name +" ::" + "</li>";
                // document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=medilist;
               result= getQuantity*database[i].price;
               document.getElementById("n4").value=result;
               remaing_stock=database[i].total_stock-getQuantity;
               document.getElementById("n2").value=remaing_stock;
        } else {
           console.log("not found");
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I want only one thing when I enter my medicine name if its name exceeded to 10 alphabets it gives me error message.

How can I do this please help. How I check this condition.
I am new in this language and facing very problems please people help me.

Comment: Formatted code, improved english, corrected grammatical mistakes

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, remember always to break for loop if you found your item.

You can use .length function to get the length of the string and use if statement to check if it is what you expect

```js
var database=[];
// var total_quantity=100;
// var counter=0;
var panadol={
    medicine_name:"panadol",
    price:12,
    total_stock:2000

};
var favrine={
    medicine_name:"favrine",
    price:38,
    total_stock:1200

};
var rivotril={
    medicine_name:"rivotril",
    price:24,
    total_stock:1500

};
database.push(panadol);
database.push(favrine);
database.push(rivotril);
console.log(database);







function search(){
    var searchmedi=document.getElementById("n1").value;
    if(searchmedi.length<10){
      var getQuantity=document.getElementById("n3").value;
      var medilist=" ";
      var result="";
      var remaing_stock;

      for(var i=0;i<database.length;i++)
      {
          if(database[i].medicine_name==searchmedi)
          {
                 result= getQuantity*database[i].price;
                 document.getElementById("n4").value=result;
                 remaing_stock=database[i].total_stock-getQuantity;
                 document.getElementById("n2").value=remaing_stock;
                 break; // remember to break if you found your item
          }


          else if(i==database.length-1){
             console.log("Medicine not found");
          }    
    }


    }
    else{
      console.log("Name is too long");
    }

}
```

```html
<marquee behavior="slid" direction="right">Wellcome To Our Medicine Store</marquee>
<div id="inps">
  Search Medicine:  <input type="text" name="n1" id="n1">
  <button onclick="search()" >Search</button>
  <br><br>
  Quantity Of Medicine:<input type="text" name="n3" id="n3">
 <br><br>
  Remaining Stock:<input type="text" name="n2" id="n2">
  <br><br>
  Total Bill:<input type="text" name="n4" id="n4">

</div>
```